# Install Application using a batch file

Tags: installation, batch-file, silent

I work at a company and I have to write a script that silently installs applications to thousands of users. I know how to do that but the only problem is this specific application has certain things that have to be selected while in the installation process. Is there any kind of command that allows me to predefine those selections so that the application installs automatically without anyone having to manually enter them? Please and thank you

Comment: You're probably going to need an installer packager. - http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-apps-for-creating-installation-packages/

Answer (score 2):

It depends entirely on the application.

Some applications have mass deployment toolkits (Office, for example) and some don't.  Some have a process where you can generate an answer file for the installer and some don't.  Some have [undocumented silent install switches](http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php) and some don't.  Some installers extract a slew of .msi files into your local temp as the first part of the install and you can run those.  Some don't.

Contact the vendor.  If they give you funny looks, you might get lucky throwing command-line switches at an executable (I have, more times than you might expect).  If not, you'll likely need to follow joeqwerty's advice above and buy an installer packager.

Answer (score 0):

AutoIt may work. It can do things like click buttons and checkboxes, and fill in fields. It's not the most friendly tool to get up and running, and it's definitely a kluge, but may be worth checking out.

https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/